# onSensorChanged fired right after register

Tags: android, sensors

I have register a `STEP_COUNTER` sensor.
If I run my app alone the `onSensorChanged` **NOT FIRED** right after `registerListener()` it only fired when I walk

However the problem is if I have another app also use `STEP_COUNTER` sensor and is running in my phone. Then `onSensorChanged` of my app always **FIRED** right after `registerListener()`.

Why it happened and how to prevent it?  I don't want onSensorChanged fired right after `registerListener().
Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    stepCounter = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, stepCounter, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
   if(sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER){
        Log.d("TAG","Sensor call");
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you want. Do you want to delay the result?

Comment: This is normal behavior. Add boolean flag when you want to start listening to it.

Comment: @Qamar why it is normal?

Comment: You should not be using Toast for logging, you should actually use logs to help you debug what you're doing. Don't use Toast for debugging.

Comment: @JoxTraex thank you I will use Log next time. but in my case `Toast` absolutely don't cause the problem. I'm sure `onSensorChanged` get fired right after `registerListener`

Comment: Oh I know, not saying its causing your issue, just that toast has limitations when its comes to debugging stuff. Its best to use Log whenever debugging something :)

Comment: @Qamar when you say about boolean flag, can you explain more about it. we can not **always** ignore the first time onSensorChanged fired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onSensorChanged` will get fired when an update interval elapsed. If a second app is listening to sensor data the elapsed interval might happen right when your app started listening. You should not rely on any timings of the sensor data. It's "user generated" data and can not be trusted.

Also, as of the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_STEP_COUNTER):

> A sensor of this type returns the number of steps taken by the user since the last reboot while activated.

You will have to store the first value you receive to track delta measurements.

Your specific problem seems to be related to the reporting mode. [The documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#REPORTING_MODE_ON_CHANGE), again, will provide you the relevant information.

> Note: If other applications are requesting a higher rate, the sensor data might be delivered at faster rates than requested.

Comment: can we know `onSensorChanged` fired because we walk **not** the first app is running.
Because inside `onSensorChanged` method I want to do some thing in first time we walk

Comment: What kind of values does `onSensorChanged` give you? If `onSensorChanged` says the user walked a step, you should treat this is a fact.